# SFTP server permission setup

Tags: permissions, ftp, sftp

I want to setup SFTP server with special permisions, but i dont know whitch program IS the best, and most importantly, how to setup the idea

My idea: You access Via secure ftp protocol, and you can ONLY upload files, cant download,read, overwrite, delete

Is that idea possible ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

First, create a directory to be accessible by `user`. Here `user` is just a local user. Replace it with whatever user you want

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/sftp/files
```

Change the ownership of the `files` directory to sftp user so that `user` can read and write on this directory.

```
sudo chown user:user/var/sftp/files
```

Set the owner and group owner of the `/var/sftp` to `root`. This will ensure that files can be uploaded only in one directory i.e. `files` and not in the parent directory.

```
sudo chown root:root /var/sftp
sudo chmod 755 /var/sftp
```

Now, edit the SSH config file

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Append these lines to the end of the file

```
Match User user
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /var/sftp
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Replace `user` with the username from above.
Finally, save the configuration and restart SSH service

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```